# How to check if fetching data from REST Web services has completed in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

The method I use to fetch data from REST web services is from: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b

However, I bump into a problem like this:

```
//First step: Push all data into an array named tempArray
var tempArray = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  this.http.get('localhost:9000/getStudentInfoById/'+i).map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    tempArray.push(data);
  });
}
//Second step: Do something with the 3 elements in tempArray.
```

In step 2, I will do some stuff with 3 elements in tempArray. Before reaching that step, I want to make Angular wait for data to fill out tempArray, because getting data from REST web services need time, so if Angular jump to the second step before fetching data, it has not (or not enough) data to manipulate.
In my case, do you know any solution? Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Move the second step inside the subscribe method.

Comment: since the http calls are inside the for loop, and the `Second step` is outside, I assume you want to get the data of all 3 request before doing the `Second step`.

that would be handle multiple http request and wait for it all to complete

Comment: @Joe Hany No, the second step use all 3 elements in tempArray at once, if I move it inside subscribe, it means second step will in for loop as well. As a result, I can use data from each element in tempArray only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is use `Observable.forkJoin` or `Observable.zip` to get all the values from the server at once. Imagine it as `Promise.all` but for `Observables.`

So, something like

```
processData() {
  let arrayOfObservables = [];
  for (let i =0; i < 3; i++) {
    //pushes all observables into an array
    this.arrayOfObservables.push(this.http.get(`${url}/i)))
  }
  return Observable.forkJoin(this.arrayOfObservables);
}
```

And then somewhere in your code:

`processData().subscribe(data => console.log(data) //all the values into an array, data[0] being the data from the first index that you got.)`

Comment: Thank you. It's what I need!!!